# Adding multi columns and foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I`m a beginner in structured query language . I want to add multi columns with different foreign key.**Like the example:**

```
drop schema humman;

create schema humman;

CREATE TABLE humman.father (
id int not null auto_increment,
firstname varchar(200) not null,
primary key(id)
);

create table humman.mather(
id int not null auto_increment,
FirstName varchar(200),
primary key(id)
);

CREATE TABLE humman.child (
id int not null auto_increment,
firstname varchar(200) not null,
primary key(id)
);

use `humman`;

alter table humman.child 
ADD `parentId` int ,
ADD `motherId` int,
ADD  foreign key (`parentId`) references father(`id`),
ADD foreign key (`motherId`) references mother(`id`);
```

> Error code: 1215 Cannot add foreign key CONSTRAINT

Comment: not mather but mother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good except for a typo, you spelt "mother" as "mather" in your second table definition;

```
create table humman.mather(
id int not null auto_increment,
FirstName varchar(200),
primary key(id)
);
```

correct that and it should work.